# Output directories for python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel

Tags: python, package, setuptools, sdist

When doing

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

it creates `build`, `dist`, `packagename.egg-info` directories. I'd like to have them out of the current folder.

I tried:

- `--dist-dir=../dist`: works with `sdist` but `packagename.egg-info` is still there
- `--bdist-dir=../dist`: for example:

  ```
     python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel --dist-dir=../dist  --bdist-dir=../dist2
  ```

  works and the final bdist package is in `../dist`. But the current folder still gets new directories `build`, `dist`, `packagename.egg-info`, which I don't want.

**Question: how to have everything (the output of sdist and bdist_wheel) outside of the current folder?**

Of course I can write a script with `mv`, `rm -r`, etc. but I wanted to know if there exists a built-in solution.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1347

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried some time again with `-d`, `--dist-dir`, `--bdist-dir` but I found no way to do it in one-line.

I'm afraid the shortest we could find (on Windows) is:

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
rmdir /s /q packagename.egg-info build ..\dist
move dist ..
```

Answer (score 3):

`setup.py` takes a *series* of commands (`setup.py --help` shows usage: `setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]`). Critically, each command is its own script with its own command line options (which is why `setup.py bdist_wheel --help`  shows different options than `setup.py sdist --help`).

The subtlety here is that certain commands generate calls to other commands under the hood but aren't nice enough to pass along common flags to the generated commands. For example, `bdist_wheel` ends up calling `build` and also `egg_info` but it does *not* pass along any `bdist-dir` you may specify. There's no global "use such and such working directory for the whole setup.py command" because all the commands are running independently and without knowledge of each other.

In order to redirect all temp directories somewhere else you have to manually specify each command and use its temp directory flag. In my case for `bdist_wheel` the full invocation was:

```
  python setup.py ^
    build --build-base \path\to\working\dir ^
    egg_info --egg-base \path\to\working\dir ^
    bdist_wheel --dist-dir \path\to\final\output\dir
```

(Side note, I found that if `build-base` and `egg-base` didn't match I got a weird error about not having used relative paths.)

This was sufficient to put all temp directories outside of the source folder.

Unfortunately it's not directly obvious which temp directory is the result of which command. You can use the list of commands (`setup.py --help-commands`) and some guesswork to determine which command created each temp directory. Then use `--help` on that command to see how to change its working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the command:

```
python setup.py egg_info --egg-base /tmp sdist bdist_wheel
```

That will put the .egg_info folder in the tmp-folder.
At least, it will be outside of your source folder.

Answer (score 0):

For using cmake, I am using this `CMakeLists.txt` with the same directory of `setup.py` can output all intermedia files out of source code dir.

```
add_custom_target(wheel
    COMMENT "python wheel build ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
    COMMAND python3 setup.py build --build-base=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} egg_info --egg-base ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} bdist_wheel --dist-dir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dist
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```